# A Small Python 2.5.4 Program: Does This Code Do The Desired Job?

Tags: python, performance, output

I'm learning the Python 2.5.4 programming language using the MIT OCW Scholar course 6.00.

I have written a program, but with the same input, my program's output differs from the output that the MIT people have shown the program to produce.

I wish to write a Python 2.5.4 program that will get current outstanding balance and annual interest rate as input from the user, and then uses the bisection search method to find the minimum fixed minimum monthly payment that would cause the balance to fall below zero within 12 months. Then the program displays the right monthly amount, the number of months needed to claer the outstanding amount, and the final balance.

Here's my code:

```
# Start of code 
balance = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: '))

interestRate = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest     rate as a decimal: '))

lower = balance / 12.0

upper = ( balance * ( 1 + interestRate / 12.0 ) ** 12.0 ) / 12.0

payment = ( lower + upper ) / 2.0

currentBalance = balance

while currentBalance > 0:
    for months in range(1, 13):
        currentBalance = currentBalance * ( 1 + interestRate / 12.0 ) - payment
        if currentBalance <= 0:
            break
    if currentBalance <= 0:
        break
    else:
        lower = payment
        payment = ( lower + upper ) / 2.0
        currentBalance = balance

print 'RESULT'
print 'Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:', '$' +   str(round(payment, 2))
print 'Number of months needed:', months
print 'Balance:', '$' + str(round(currentBalance, 2))
#End of code
```

Does my code do the desired job? If not, where lies the problem? And, how to fix it? Even if the program is right, in what ways can it be improved?

Please do bear in mind that I'm a only a beginner.

Regards.

Comment: what does your code output compared to the MIT expected output?

Comment: Python 2.5.4 is now 8 years old.  Guido himself said 'Everybody should be using python 3 by now'. Why python 2.5?

Comment: @MaxNoe easier said than done, not every important library has been ported to my knowledge e.g. Twisted

Comment: @Woot4Moo well, the output values diverge widely despite my giving the same input as in they have. What's your assessment about the code here? Should it work correctly?

Comment: @MaxNoe: I presume this is the course: `http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/software/` - it seems to have been designed in spring 2011 and calls for "any 2.5 or 2.6 version of Python".

Comment: It seems odd to use floats and this line ` 1 + interestRate / 12.0 ) ** 12.0 )`  why are you raising it to the power of 12?

Comment: For one thing you need a minus sign before "payment" in your "currentBalance = currentBalance * ( 1 + interestRate / 12.0 )      payment" line.

Comment: @Woot4Moo you see, our goal is to find the minimum monthly payment that will cause the current balance to get below zero within 12 months. Now the maximum balance after 12 months is what I've assigned to my variable upper, which will result if the monthly payment were zero. On the other hand, if the monthly payment has to be at least one twelfth of the initial balance for the balance to go below zero within a year.

Comment: Even if one needs a library that has not been ported yet,  there is python 2.7.10.  There should really be no point for using python 2.5

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos (which may have been introduced when copying into your posting):

- you split `balance on your credit` / `card:` across a line-ending, which will give a SyntaxError
- `currentBalance = currentBalance * ( 1 + interestRate / 12.0 )      payment` is missing a `-` operator before `payment`

The first logical error is

```
    if currentBalance <= 0:
        break
```

... you stop as soon as you find a **higher than needed** payment; you only ever increase possible payment values (`lower = payment`), never decrease it (you should have a clause leading to `upper = payment`, otherwise your bisection search will be lopsided).

Once you do that, you will have to add a new test to know when to stop looping. What is your target accuracy - payment to the nearest cent? How will you know when you have found it?

My only other suggestion would be to improve your code organization by defining some operations as functions - `get_float(prompt)` and `final_balance(current_balance, interest_rate, num_payments)` are obvious candidates.

Comment: yes, you correctly identified the typos, but those typos weren't there in the original program; they only crept in while I was trying to indent the code four spaces after pasting it in the Stack Overflow edit box. The bisection has to be lop-sided since we're only aiming to make the current balance equal zero or go below zero within 12 months.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: but you are supposed to find the **minimum** higher-than-needed payment! **Any** higher-than-needed payment doesn't work.